# Using multiple query conditions in MongoDB's UpdateOne statement

Tags: javascript, sql, mongodb, express

I am trying to update a query using 'updateOne' with multiple conditions.
when I put a single Codition it works fine.
or when I ordered the highly unique identifier first in condition, then it works fine.
but when I change it's order it seems jammed and inserting multiple document with different _id.

follwoing is my Javascript code code.

```
const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
await posts.updateOne(
{ 
    "timestamp" : jsoned_body.timestamp ,
    "transactionID" : jsoned_body.transactionID ,                   
    "deviceSN" : jsoned_body.deviceSN ,
},
{
    $set: 
    {
        "transactionID": jsoned_body.transactionID,   
        "deviceName": jsoned_body.deviceName,   
        "deviceSN": jsoned_body.deviceSN,   
        "userID": jsoned_body.userID                         
    }   
},     
{ upsert: true }
)

async function loadPostsCollection() {    
    const client = await 
    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${config.DB_IPAddr}:${config.DB_PortNo}/tms`, {
    });
    return client.db('tms').collection('transactionLogs');
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: May be updateMany?

Comment: @MikiBelavista to use multiple conditions to find matched documents, Should I use UpdateMany?

Comment: If you query a posts.find( {"timestamp" : jsoned_body.timestamp , "transactionID" : jsoned_body.transactionID , "deviceSN" : jsoned_body.deviceSN} ) what do you get?